# TypeError: execute() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) - execute method sqlite3 Jython

Tags: python, sqlite, typeerror, jython, execute

I'm currently working on a Python script run via Jython 2.7 and I'm using sqlite3 module for Jython ([link](https://pypi.org/project/jython-sqlite3/)) whose syntax is identical to CPython sqlite3 module.

Here is the code:

```py
    def file_exists(self, cur, file_hash):
        cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM samples WHERE file_hash = ?", (file_hash,))
        ret = cur.fetchone()
        if ret is None:
            return False
        return True
```

```
cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM samples WHERE file_hash = ?", (file_hash,))
TypeError: execute() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I looked around on the Internet and syntax seems to be right, so I don't understand what's causing this issue.

**EDIT:**

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import json
import logging
import sqlite3
from hashlib import sha1

ANALYSIS_FAILED = 0
ANALYSIS_SUCCESS = 1
ANALYSIS_ALREADY = 2

class ProgramAnalyzer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = None
        self.cyclomatic_complexities = None
        self.primes = None
        self.signature = None
        self.file_hash = None
        self.total_functions = 0
        self.analysis_date = None
        self.architecture = None

    def file_exists(self, cur, file_hash):
        cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM samples WHERE file_hash = ?", (file_hash,))
        ret = cur.fetchone()
        if ret is None:
            return False
        return True

    def analyze(self):
        t = time.time()

        executable_path = getCurrentProgram().getExecutablePath()
        content = open(executable_path, 'r').read()
        self.file_hash = sha1(content).hexdigest()

        # Checking whether such file is already in the database
        conn = cur = None
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
            cur = conn.cursor()
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            logging.error("Database error: " + str(e))
            return ANALYSIS_FAILED

        if self.file_exists(cur, self.file_hash):
            return ANALYSIS_ALREADY
        print("File not in database")

        [initializing remaining object fields]

        return ANALYSIS_SUCCESS

def main():
    analyzer = ProgramAnalyzer()
    ret = analyzer.analyze()
    if ret == ANALYSIS_FAILED:
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Functions like *getCurrentProgram()* and *getExecutablePath()* are some Java API I'm using.

Comment: How did you instantiate `cur` ?

Comment: conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

Comment: And what class defines `file_exists`, and how to you call `file_exists`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: `if self.file_exists(db, self.file_hash):`

Comment: My entire code works fine except for such cur.execute().

Comment: @Benny if we run the code above, we will have to guess how `cur` and `file_hash` are defined, as well as how the encompassing class is constructed, which makes it harder to give an accurate answer to help

Comment: @Benny so basically you did `db = conn.cursor()` ?

Comment: Edited with more code

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with jython-sqlite3. 
 It has a different signature for `Cursor.execute()`: https://github.com/anthonyhendrickson/jython-sqlite3/blob/master/sqlite3/module.py#L27

That is, different from the signature of the same function in the Python standard library, which supports SQL parameters: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

Comment: Oh god, I didn't see that! So there is no way to get parametrized queries, am I right?

Comment: Looks like you are rolling your own.